# Finding table source for increased UPDATES in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

One of the Postgres databases I'm monitoring is getting swamped with a ton of UPDATES.  What's the best method in Postgres to easily identify what table or tables in my instance is getting the bulk of these DML requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `pg_stat_all_tables` for it, like here:

```
t=# create table t19 (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t19 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select schemaname,relname,n_tup_upd from pg_stat_all_tables order by n_tup_upd desc limit 2;
 schemaname |     relname     | n_tup_upd
------------+-----------------+-----------
 pg_catalog | pg_operator     |         0
 pg_catalog | pg_auth_members |         0
(2 rows)

t=# update t19 set i=2;
UPDATE 1
t=# update t19 set i=2;
UPDATE 1
t=# select schemaname,relname,n_tup_upd from pg_stat_all_tables order by n_tup_upd desc limit 2;
 schemaname |   relname   | n_tup_upd
------------+-------------+-----------
 public     | t19         |         2
 pg_catalog | pg_operator |         0
(2 rows)
```